# python, I am not able to save special characters, such as θæŋ after making re,search

Tags: python, regex, character-encoding, django-admin

I am not able to save special characters, such as θæŋ after making re.search.

I am saving to the Django model Textfield. in Admin page, Instead of θæŋkfəli, i am getting

```
\xce\xb8\xc3\xa6\xc5\x8bkf\xc9\x99li
```

Is it error of re.search? 
Is it error of Admin? 
Am i saving wrongly?

How to search for needed part of string an save it in the Textfield of the model with 'θæŋ' characters?

```
lines='title="Listen to audio" /></a><span class="pr">/<span class="unicode">ˈ</span>θæŋkfəli/</span> <span class="fl">adverb' #the string which i wan to save exactly as it is, Django saves it correctly

liness=smart_str(lines, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='replace') # saves correctly
linesu=smart_unicode(lines, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='replace')  # saves correctly
```

After trying to seach part of string θæŋkfəli Django does not save it in needed special characters. Instead of θæŋkfəli, I am getting "\xce\xb8\xc3\xa6\xc5\x8bkf\xc9\x99li"

```
stryc=re.compile('<span\s*class=\"pr\">\s*/\s*<span\s*class="unicode\">(?P<Pronun>.*)<span\s*class=\"fl\">', re.DOTALL)
                    #\s+/\s+<span class=\"unicode\">\s+[\\a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/\s+</span> '
strys=re.search(stryc, linesu)

Pronun=stryWordcs.groups('Pronun')
text=Pronun.encode('utf-8') # does not covert unicode to letters
Pronun=smart_str(Pronun, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='replace') # also does not covert unicode to letters
a=Pronunciation(field=Pronun) # or field=text
a.save()
# Pronun=  "θæŋkfəli", nevertheless it is saved as  \xce\xb8\xc3\xa6\xc5\x8bkf\xc9\x99li or in unicode
```

if i do not use smart_str, i am getting "\u03b8\xe6\u014bkf\u0259li"

if i try to search in lines or liness i am not able to find  θæŋkfəli due special character  ˈ (small stick on top =\xcb\x88 = \u02c8)

regards,
gintare

Answer (score 1):

When you see `"\xce\xb8\xc3\xa6\xc5\x8bkf\xc9\x99li`, what you're seeing is in fact the same as θæŋkfəli, but in hexadecimal notation. Similarly, you could represent the same set of characters as

`U+03B8 U+00E6 U+014BkfU+0259li`

This is because the text is stored as a unicode string. To see that this is actually the same, try copying your text (with the special characters) into the top box in [this conversion website](http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/) and hitting convert. Python is able to [handle unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) but depending on what you're using to display the characters it's going to come out differently.

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. If you're concerned about your regular expression being able to accurately match the unicode characters, python's `re` module has an option to [make it work differently with unicode](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.U).

If you're concerned about how this text is being displayed, this is going to vary based on how you're trying to display it, and you'll need to be more specific about your problem.

I can assure you though, that Django is storing your string just fine.